# Does MSSQL Server have the equivalent of MySQL's query logs?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, log-files, logging

I have used MySQL for a long time and have found the general query log and the slow query log to be very useful in finding out what is happening on the server, and in identifying bottlenecks.

Now I need to use SQL Server. Does SQL Server have similar log facilities? If so, what are they called?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

SQL server keeps statistical information about all queries in various tables. You can use the following code to determine what the longest running query is (from the `sys.dm_exec_query_stats` table).

You should run the following DBCC commands:

This DBCC command clears the server cache and restarts logging of the query running time:

```
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE
```

Run this query to find the longest running query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 10
 t.TEXT QueryName,
 s.execution_count AS ExecutionCount,
 s.max_elapsed_time AS MaxElapsedTime,
 ISNULL(s.total_elapsed_time / s.execution_count, 0) AS AvgElapsedTime,
 s.creation_time AS LogCreatedOn,
 ISNULL(s.execution_count / DATEDIFF(s, s.creation_time, GETDATE()), 0) AS FrequencyPerSec
 FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats s
 CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text( s.sql_handle ) t
 ORDER BY
 s.max_elapsed_time DESC
 GO
```

You should also take a look at the *Technet* magazine article [Optimizing SQL Server Query Performance](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2007.11.sqlquery.aspx), which has a query for determining which query is the most expensive read I/O query, as well as guidance on how to look at execution plans and other optimizations.

Comment: The MSSQL Database Engine Tuning Advisor is invaluable in chasing down those missing indexes and statistics to speed up the long-running queries (mind you, nothing will help if if it's long-running because of a locked row). If you've got a few hours to spare, capture a few minutes with the trace tool and then load the trace into the tuning advisor. It will go through every query and tell you if it can be sped up, and approximately how much by.

Comment: The problem wth trace is that it is not a log.  If the question was "how do I analyse sql server performance"  I would certainly be responding with something about profiler.

Answer (score 3):

You can use SQL Profiler to monitor the system in real time to identify slow running statements.

Comment: +1 - the trace facility is pretty good

Answer (score 1):

SQL can also suggest indexes you might like to add or elimitate:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187974.aspx

You can also see reports in SQL Management studio related to long queries:
Right-click your servername > reports > standard reports > Performance - Top Queries by...

Answer (score 0):

Old slow queries are saved in MSSQL. This was already solved here:

http://blog.brianhartsock.com/2008/12/16/quick-and-dirty-sql-server-slow-query-log/